# Find 100-th derivative of $1/(x^2+x+1)$ at x = 0

Tags: power-series

The hint is using power series. So I use Taylor's formula but still cannot reduce it. Any other hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$\frac1{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=(1-x)(1+x^3+x^6+\cdots).$$

Comment: Got it, thanks...

Comment: So what is the 100th derivative ?